# Is there a way to share environment variables and secrets among lambda functions in Amplify?

Tags: aws-amplify

Right now I have to create environment variables and secrets per each function separately even though some might be using the same values. Unfortunately, we cannot set environment variables and secrets for lambda layers. Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is currently not possible because secrets in amplify are function binded "/amplify/${appId}/${env}/AMPLIFY_${functionName}_"